# Why following codes shows Unsupported operand types error?

Tags: php

Why following codes shows this error?

> Xdebug: Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in
>   C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\testtheme\single-football_league.php
>   on line 63.

```
foreach (array_keys($team_points + $team_points2) as $key) {
        $total_points_final[$key] = (isset($team_points[$key]) ? $team_points[$key] : 0) + (isset($team_points2[$key]) ? $team_points2[$key] : 0);
    }
```

Comment: Probably because one of those two variables: `$team_points`, `$team_points2` is not an array. What is the output of: `var_dump($team_points);` and `var_dump($team_points2);`?

Comment: This is a good example of code that shouldn't be using a ternary operator... very hard to read.

Comment: null and 
array (size=1)
  '' => int 34
respectively.

Comment: `null` does not look like an array does it?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to concatenate $team_points and $team_points2? If so, you should use array_merge: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

```
foreach (array_keys( array_merge($team_points, $team_points2)) as $key) {
        $total_points_final[$key] = (isset($team_points[$key]) ? $team_points[$key] : 0) + (isset($team_points2[$key]) ? $team_points2[$key] : 0);
    }
```