# Why these codes show Unsupported operand types and others errors?

Tags: php

I am a beginner.Why following codes show three errors?:

> 1) Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\testtheme\functions.php on line 851
>
> 2) Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\testtheme\functions.php on line 851 
>   851 line:

```
foreach (array_keys($team_points + $team_points2) as $key) {
    $total_points_final[$key] = (isset($team_points[$key]) ? $team_points[$key] : 0) + (isset($team_points2[$key]) ? $team_points2[$key] : 0);
}
```

> 3) Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\testtheme\functions.php on line 859
>   859 line:

```
foreach (array_keys($total_points_final + $team_points3) as $key) {
    $total_points_final2[$key] = (isset($total_points_final[$key]) ? $total_points_final[$key] : 0) + (isset($team_points3[$key]) ? $team_points3[$key] : 0);
}
```

All codes:

```
$total_points=0;
    $team_points;
    $team_points2;
    $team_points3;
    foreach($team_wins as $tw_key=>$tw_val){
        $team_points[$tw_key]=$tw_val*3;
    }

    foreach($team_drawn as $tw_key=>$tw_val){
        $team_points2[$tw_key]=$tw_val*1;
    }

    $total_points_final = array();
    $total_points_final2 = array();
    foreach (array_keys($team_points + $team_points2) as $key) {
        $total_points_final[$key] = (isset($team_points[$key]) ? $team_points[$key] : 0) + (isset($team_points2[$key]) ? $team_points2[$key] : 0);
    }

    foreach($team_loses as $tw_key=>$tw_val){
        $team_points3[$tw_key]=$tw_val*0;
    }

    foreach (array_keys($total_points_final + $team_points3) as $key) {
        $total_points_final2[$key] = (isset($total_points_final[$key]) ? $total_points_final[$key] : 0) + (isset($team_points3[$key]) ? $team_points3[$key] : 0);
    }
```

Comment: Be sure to use the right parameter for array_key, See http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-keys.php, can be great to use a "," instead of "+" in the function?

Comment: RTM, [http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

Comment: You already asked a very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39821343/3933332 and again some of your variables are probably not an array when thy should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only supply *array_keys()* a valid array which it inturn returns the keys  of the array passed into it as an argument.

It would never except any variable type
You can create a new empty array like this:

```
$arr = [];
```

Then add those values to the empty array like this:

```
$arr[] = $post_id;
$arr[] = $post_total;
```

Now you can call the new array in your *array_keys($arr)*

Answer (score 0):

```
1. array_keys() => The array_keys() function takes only array  parameter, you cannot pass integer or string.  
example:
$array = array("name"=>"xyz", "email"=>"xxxxxxx@xxxx.xxx");
array_keys($array); //Valid
array_keys(2);//Invalid/Error

2. foreach
  foreach is a looping statement, you cannot pass inetger or string to loop it, 
  pass array to foreach, you cannot pass empty array to foreach,
  check empty condition before passing to foreach

  example:
  foreach($array as $key=>$value) { //valid input for foreach
        echo $value;
  }
```